# Binding to code-behind dynamic variable not working in a multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to do an application that allows me to create projects, and i got a problem in my window that's displaying or encoding the path of the project to create : i have a Textbox that need to display the concatenation of 2 strings : the content of another Textbox (which is working (actually, workED, cause as soon as i added the other Binding it stopped displaying)) and the content of a Code-behind variable that contain the path of the executable. However, even if the string contain the valid path when the window launches, nothing is displayed in the Textbox. Does there is something that i didn't understand for the binding ? I read multiple thing and thought i've done it well but something doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Nom" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="newProject_name" Text="Project"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Chemin" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox x:Name="newProject_path" Width="auto">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}\\{1}.lmd">
                        <Binding Path="applicationPath"/>
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="newProject_name"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <Button x:Name="newProject_parcourir" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="0,5,0,0" Click="newProject_parcourir_Click">
                <TextBlock Text="Parcourir"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

---

```
 public partial class CreateProjectWindow : Window
{
    public string applicationPath { get; set; }
    public CreateProjectWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        applicationPath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    }

    private void newProject_parcourir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
 
    }
    private void newProject_annuler_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

---

So i'd want to display both the content of the Textbox named "newProject_name" and the content of the dynamic variable "applicationPath", which is a string.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you have done seems to be working. Perhaps you could supply some more information of your problem along with the expected output? Not necessarily, but screenshots sometimes might be useful.

Comment: You have to set the Window's DataContext to itself, e.g. `DataContext = this;` in the constructor. Or as shown in the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens, it did the trick! Sorry if the question was a duplicate, but i don't really understand why the two have similarities. I'll read more about the DataContext.